# C# Find control, casting, elegant code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a ASPX  / C# application. It uses gridviews and template fields with controls on them. To access the dynamic controls I am using the findcontrol method and it all works fine.

But as the app is getting bigger, I can see code to find controls getting repeated in different functions / button click events. I am thinking it would be good to create a generic function that finds controls based to parameters passed to it. I am a c# beginner and need to know if this possible? or the control type has to be specified?

This is what I am working with (The function is not tested so might be a flawed idea).

Code in click events:

```
    Button btn = (Button)sender;   
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    TextBox details = gvr.FindControl("detailsText") as TextBox;
    //do something with details 
    TextBox cusID = gvr.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
    // do something with cusID
```

The function I want to write

```
   protected Control Returncontrol(GridViewRow gvr, String ControlName)
{
    TextBox aCon = gvr.FindControl(ControlName) as TextBox;
    // This bit is what I am not sure about. Is possible to find the control without specifying what type of control it is? 
    return aCon;
}
```

This is how I aim to use the function:

```
Returncontrol(gvr, TextBox2).text ="Something";
```

Comment: `"TextBox2"`? Fix that first.

Comment: This is pseudocode, I am talking about the idea as a concept.

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what you are trying to do here and what your actual question is. Since `TextBox` inherits from `Control` you should be able to return it from your `Returncontrol` (should be `ReturnControl`) function. A better option, however, might be to look at using a generic function `T ReturnControl<T>`?

Comment: The names get dynamically changed and I find them using:     Button btn = (Button)sender;   
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method using generic type parameter and the caller can specify the type of Control expecting back like:

```
protected TControl Returncontrol<TControl>(GridViewRow gvr, String ControlName) 
                                                                  where TControl : Control
{
    TControl control = gvr.FindControl(ControlName) as TControl;

    return control;
}
```

Now you will be using it like:

```
TextBox txtBox = ReturnControl<TextBox>(grid1,"TextBox1");
```

and now you can access the properties and methods available on `TextBox` type :

```
if(txtBox!=null)
    txtBox.Text ="Something";
```

You can also create an extension method on the `GridViewRow` type for this as an option like:

```
public static class GridViewRowExtensions
{
   public static TControl Returncontrol<TControl>(this GridViewRow gvr, String ControlName) where TControl : Control
   {
        TControl control = gvr.FindControl(ControlName) as TControl;

        return control;
   }
}
```

and now you can directly call it using the instance of `GridViewRow` :

```
TextBox txtBox = gvr.ReturnControl<TextBox>("TextBox1");

if(txtBox!=null)
    txtBox.Text="Some Text";
```

Hope it gives you idea on how to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to implement option one and I get errors saying; can't convert web.ui.control to TControl and also TControl can't be used with as operator.

Comment: you need to add constraint like :  `protected TControl Returncontrol<TControl>(GridViewRow gvr, String ControlName) 
                                                                  where TControl : Control`, updated post too

Comment: Thanks. All sorted. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a static helper class with an extension method:

```
public static class ControlHelper
{
    public static T GetCtrl<T>(this Control c, string name) where T : Control
    {
        return c.FindControl(name) as T;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
using _namespace_of_ControlHelper_ ;

// ...
TextBox txtBox = gvr.GetCtrl<TextBox>("TextBox1");
```